# Fast voice recognition for limited number of commands

Tags: c++, windows, voice-recognition

Does anyone have experience programming voice recognition in C++ (Windows and/or Mac) for a limited number of commands aiming for SPEED? Is it realistic at this point to achieve recognition of the command from the first syllable - ie, command is recognized by the time user gets to second syllable at reasonably fast speaking tempo? All commands would be programmed to start with a different syllable, if necessary, a radically different one (like, "oo", "xy", "fay" - only some 30 commands would be required).
Similar questions have been asked, but this is a fast moving field. Would the best idea be to look for open source libraries or to interface with compiled implementations?

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: He's not asking for help with a library choice, he's wondering whether the field is mature enough that libraries exist in the first place. NOT off-topic, +1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working professionally in this field, and I seriously doubt whether it is possible at all. C++ isn't the problem, the question is whether a computer allows it. The error rate on small sound clips is large, it's the Hidden Markov Model that fixes recognition. But in your case you simply can't feed it enough data.

Not that humans can do it either. Speech processing isn't as instant as your brain makes you believe.

Comment: That is why I was thinking about using commands with highly characteristic sounds, using only a small set of syllables that contrast each other as much as possible. Even a cat can recognize "shh" immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net) with Pocketsphinx decoder.

The partial hypothesis of decoding is avaiable during the recognition process and you can usually get a first syllable as soon as it is uttered. If you give it 0.1s to stabilize (not visible for the user), you will get an accurate results on a command set.

There are even tools build on the top of CMUSphinx specifically designed for realtime control, for example in games, you can check [InProTK](http://www.inpro.tk/) and their demonstrations.

Comment: Is it faster than using Windows SAPI? I'm not interested in mobile applications, only PC with a lot of processing power. This "written in Java" for CMUSphinx threw me off a little bit, I'm sure that it could be fast enough, but wouldn't native Microsoft API be faster?

Comment: Pocketsphinx is a C decoder and it's available simply from C++. See for details http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx. You misread something about Java.